# Excluding a directory from Jekyll watch

Tags: jekyll

I'm using Jekyll 3.1.1 to generate a blog and I recently introduced a Git hook to automatically publish changes pre-push.

After introducing this hook, I have started getting the following error when I run `jekyll serve`:

```
Configuration file: /Users/egillespie/Projects/blog.givingjar.org/_config.yml
            Source: /Users/egillespie/Projects/blog.givingjar.org
       Destination: /Users/egillespie/Projects/blog.givingjar.org/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating... 
                    done in 0.223 seconds.
        ** ERROR: directory is already being watched! **

        Directory: /Users/egillespie/Projects/blog.givingjar.org/node_modules/git-scripts/bin/hooks

        is already being watched through: /Users/egillespie/Projects/blog.givingjar.org/node_modules/git-scripts/bin/hooks

        MORE INFO: https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Duplicate-directory-errors
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for '/Users/egillespie/Projects/blog.givingjar.org'
Configuration file: /Users/egillespie/Projects/blog.givingjar.org/_config.yml
    Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000/
  Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
```

What's peculiar is that I am excluding `node_modules` in `_config.yml`:

```
exclude:
  - Gemfile
  - Gemfile.lock
  - LICENSE
  - README.md
  - package.json
  - Gruntfile.js
  - node_modules
```

`node_modules` is correctly being excluded from building (i.e. there is no `node_modules` subdirectory in `_site`).

I'm also excluding `node_modules` in `.gitignore`:

```
# project
node_modules
_site*
.sass-cache
.jekyll-metadata

# general
.DS_Store
Thumbs.db
ehthumbs.db
```

Based on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/2541) and [this commit](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-watch/commit/09cfdcb60749b306dd2015d0820dadacfbefdaf9) it seems like `node_modules` should be excluded from the watch, but it's not. I can't decipher from the documentation if there's another way to exclude files from the watch.

What is the proper way for me to exclude a directory from the watch and avoid the error described above?

Comment: Is your problem resolved ? If not, can you show more about the hook itself ?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm struggling with the same watch issue a year later...

Comment: @RossR I was never able to resolve this issue. I migrated to Netlify so I would no longer need the Git hook, which worked around the scenario that caused this issue.

Comment: I [asked a question](https://talk.jekyllrb.com/t/exclude-from-watch/661) on Jekyll Talk and it seems likely the problem is on my side. My guess: I have some symlinks, and Jekyll Watch imports the parent of a symlink (probably for efficiency). Anyway, I removed the symlinks and removed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The value for exclude parameter in _config.yml should be an array i.e.

```
exclude: ['_site', 'node_modules', ...]
```

Source: [Jekyll Documentation - Configuration](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/)

Comment: The syntax I'm using is an alternative approach to creating an array in YAML. I did try it your way, though, and I still get the error. http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2759963

Comment: I found this as a working fix. See if this works for you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/36861807/428901

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this workaround, Jabran. Unfortunately, it doesn't get rid of the error in my case.

Comment: same issue, but this can not help.

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the paths displayed in your output, you're on macOS. The jekyll-watch gem is responsible for this area (watch/rebuild features), which itself depends on the 'listen' gem. The listen gem itself uses the rb-inotify gem as a dependency, which has several issues with macOS specifically and its filesystem. This results in several bugs in regeneration behaviour that aren't not easy to fix. Background and relevant bugs:

- https://github.com/guard/listen/issues/274
- https://github.com/guard/listen/pull/273

You can try using the 'polling' method: https://github.com/guard/listen#listen-adapters instead, but it's much slower.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to your `_config.yml`:

```
keep_files: [node]
```

where `node` is a folder to exclude from the `--watch`. What this will do is keeping the folder `node` [untouched by `jekyll build`](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#global-configuration). Then add all files that you want to keep in the site `root` but not rendered by Jekyll.

Comment: I added `node_modules` and I still get the error. The documentation suggests that `keep_files` tells Jekyll to leave files in `_site` alone. Unfortunately, `node_modules` is in the base of my project and Node does not offer a way to change that. I did try passing `../node_modules` to `keep_files` to see if I could trick Jekyll, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Hmm... Try `exclude: [node_modules, Gemfile, etc]` and see how it goes... If doesn't work, and none of the answers here work, you can always try asking on [Jekyll Talk](https://talk.jekyllrb.com).

Comment: I tried `exclude: [node_modules, Gemfile, etc]`, also to no avail. I'll check out Jekyll Talk and report back. Thanks.

Comment: Try adding this line to the file`.gitignore`: `node_modules`

Comment: `node_modules` is already in my `.gitignore` file. Sorry for not providing that in my question.

Comment: wow. this is definitely odd then! Better try Jekyll Talk. Ask for `@parkr` - he is "the boss" there!

Comment: I posed [the question](https://talk.jekyllrb.com/t/how-to-exclude-a-file-directory-from-watch/1940) on Jekyll Talk. \*fingers crossed\* Thanks for the referral!