# Exclude Jekyll directory from --watch, but not build

Tags: html, command-line-interface, jekyll

I have a very similar issue to [Excluding a directory from Jekyll watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35301292/excluding-a-directory-from-jekyll-watch), but I thought it was different enough to warrant it's own question.

---

**_config.yml:**

```
exclude: [
  "my_ignored_directory"
]
```

Using `jekyll build --watch`, the folder `my_ignored_directory` will be successfully ignored from the watch task, but it will also not be built.

Is there are way to exclude a folder of my choosing from the `--watch` task, but not to be excluded from being built?

(Note: there is no error in the console)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no, because excluded files for watch are : `_config.*`, `destination folder` (usually `_site`) and content of `config['exclude']`.

See [jekyll-watch code](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-watch/blob/master/lib/jekyll/watcher.rb#L57)

### Edit : But ...

We can override `Jekyll::Watcher::custom_excludes` methods with a plugin.

**_plugins/jekyll-watcher-override.rb**

```
require 'jekyll-watch'
module Jekyll
  module Watcher
    # replace old method by new method
    # new method is now :custom_excludes
    # overridden method is now :old_custom_excludes
    alias_method :old_custom_excludes, :custom_excludes
    def custom_excludes(options)
      # if we have an "exclude_from_watch" variable in configuration
      if options['exclude_from_watch'] then
        # merge exclude and exclude_from_watch
        (options['exclude'] << options['exclude_from_watch']).flatten!
      end
      # pass the new option array to overridden method
      old_custom_excludes(options)
    end
  end
end
```

In _config.yml, just set an `exclude_from_watch` variable :

```
exclude_from_watch:
  - css
```

Now, when you do a `jekyll serve` any file / folder in `exclude_from_watch` will be ignored if they change.

Comment: **Booooooo Jekyll!** - Thanks, I thought this might be the case.

Comment: Oooo. I'll definitely look into that

Comment: This seems to only work for the first couple of refreshes, and then `jekyll-watch` starts picking up the ignored directory again. Could Jekyll somehow be re-loading the watch again, and overriding the override?