# Is there a way for a folder to be included in the production build but not have jekyll compile it?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll

I think the best example for this would an `images/` folder or `node_modules/` for images & dependencies to be included in the final build without taking a really long time to compile.

edit:

sorry for not specifying but I'm well aware of `keep_files` and `exclude` and both don't help with my situation.

`exclude` excludes the folder and files from the compiling and site build and would require additional pipelining tools to move them manually each time.

`keep_files` requires the files to exist in the final build in the first place, which is not possible for some production environment (GitHub's gh-pages etc. etc.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excluding a directory from Jekyll watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35301292/excluding-a-directory-from-jekyll-watch)

Comment: I have edited my question so it's not a duplicate

Answer (score 3):

You might wanna check this out:
[Excluding a directory from Jekyll watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35301292/excluding-a-directory-from-jekyll-watch)

P.S.: Always explore stack overflow before posting a question; yours could be a duplicate or answered before. You get downvoted otherwise.